# How to convert existing Angular 4 project to webpack

Tags: angular, webpack

It's longtime I am working on an angular 4 project. Today I want to convert it to webpack.

I spent many time looking for a tutorial to do that But I have not found it.

I tried to grasp this the documentation of [angular webpack](https://angular.io/guide/webpack) but i didn't ge steps to convert the project.

Can someone please indicate me steps to follow ?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Create a new project with the angular-cli. See how it is structured and then copy your project into that structure.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of the reasons you want to make a switch to webpack from angular cli (guess your code is already using that). Personally, I always prefer using webpack directly rather than using angular cli. I believe that gives the developer more control. But, that comes with big responsibility (as is usual with great power) towards evaluating all the goods from angular cli that you are going to miss!

Anyway, [here](https://github.com/rakcheru/webpack-angular5) is a sample module that uses webpack instead of angular cli. It uses latest angular 5 but should work with angular 4 as well.

Comment: Thanks @Rakesh Kumar Cherukuri, this module doesn't work for me in 1.4.9 of angular.

Comment: angular 1.4.9 ? Didnt you mention that you are using angular 4 in your OP ?